# RegEx - stop after first match

Tags: regex, otrs

we're using this regex to filter a ticket number from the subject.

This is the regex we're using: `\\[\\#(.*)\\]`

The subject usually looks like this: `"[#20160708-0020] Hello blah blah"`

Regex get's us `"20160708-0020"` and we can use that further.

Somebody from the company started writing mails like this: `"[#20160708-0020] Hello [SQL] blah blah"`

So the regex will get us `"20160708-0020] Hello [SQL"` which obviously isn't correct.

Is there any way to tell the regex to stop after the first match? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/sY4pG6/1

```
\[\#(.*?)\]
```

The `*` in your regex is greedy. It will capture as much as possible.

The  `*?` above is lazy. It will capture as little as possible. This will make your regex stop after that first match.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!. Now how will you do it if you want to stop after the second occurrence? :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop it before it goes further, you'll want to make your expression [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

`\[\#(.*?)\]`

Notice the question mark after the asterisk.