# Extract the first complete address from string

Tags: python, regex

I am unsure how to tell a regular expression in Python to stop after finding the first match.

Apparently you can tell regex to be lazy, [RegEx - stop after first match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400595/regex-stop-after-first-match) , I tried placing (.*?) at the end of my expression but that just broke it.
I just want it to stop after finding the first complete address and return that.

Sample code with data:
https://regexr.com/6okuv

In the sample data all addresses are accepted by the expression except "Hindenburgdamm 27, Hygiene-Institut" where it should stop after "27" and return "Hindenburgdamm 27" and "Peschkestr. 5a/Holsteinische Str. 44" where it should stop after "5a" and return "Peschkestr. 5a".

```
Regex expression : 
^([A-Za-zÄäÖöÜüß\s\d.-]+?)\s*([\d\s]+(?:\s?[-+/]\s?\d+)?\s*[A-Za-z]?-?[A-Za-z]?)?$

Sample data:
Berliner Str. 74
Hindenburgdamm 27, Hygiene-Institut
Peschkestr. 5a/Holsteinische Str. 44
Lankwitzer Str. 13-17a
Fidicinstr. 15A
Haudegen Weg 15/17
Johanna-Stegen-Strasse 14a-d
Friedrichshaller Str. 7
Südwestkorso 9
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit @wiktor-stribiżew . I'll be more careful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the pattern a bit more specific for the digits and the trailing characters, and match at least a single digit using a case insensitive match:

```
^([A-ZÄäÖöÜüß.\s-]+?)\s*(\d+(?:[/-]\d+)?(?:[A-Z](?:-[A-Z])?)?)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `([A-ZÄäÖöÜüß.\s-]+?)` Capture group 1
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `(?:[/-]\d+)?` Optionally match `/` `-` and 1+ digits
  - `(?:[A-Z](?:-[A-Z])?)?` Optionally match  A-Z followed by an optional `-` and A-Z
- `)` Close group 2
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MX05aj/1)

If you want a match only and don't need the capture groups you can omit them.

Note that in the leading character class there are chars like `.`, `-` and `\s` If the match should not start with any of these characters you can start with a character class without those following by an optionally repeated character class to still match at least 1 character.

```
^[A-ZÄäÖöÜüß][A-ZÄäÖöÜüß.\s-]*?\s*\d+(?:[/-]\d+)?(?:[A-Z](?:-[A-Z])?)?\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o2hTv4/1)

Comment: Many thanks for your step-by-step explanation, I really appreciate it. It works with all my test cases in RegExr! I've been sitting at this since before lunch! This is great. Now I just have to apply it to my pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern

```
^([A-Za-zÄäÖöÜüß\s\d.-]+?\s[0-9a-zA-zÄäÖöÜüß-]+?)[\s\/,]?
```

In any case if you don't expect to match the full line don't use the $ to expect the regular expression to reach EOL.